# How to override custom Control Event?

Tags: c#, events, gridview, overriding

I made a custom gridView class which inherits from GridView.

```
public class CustomGridView : GridView {}
```

It adds a textbox in the footerRow, and I'd like to manage the changed event for this textbox directly in my page, and not in the class.

Something like :

```
public override void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

How could I do this ?

Comment: you can create an event in your class and and listen for textchange event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to add a new event to your `CustomGridView` and raise that in the handler of the `TextChanged` event of the textbox.

So, in your `CustomGridView`:

```
public event EventHandler FooterTextChanged;

private void RaiseFooterTextChanged()
{
    var handler = FooterTextChanged;
    if(handler == null)
        return;

    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

public override void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RaiseFooterTextChanged();
}
```

In the class that uses `CustomGridView`:

```
customGridView.FooterTextChanged += OnGridFooterTextChanged;
```

Comment: This works great, this is exactly what I wanted, and will be very useful in other cases. Thank you Daniel